# Create a python object that mimics string iterator behaviour

Tags: python, class, object

I'm trying to make an object which behaves like a string when it is used in "x in y" syntax.

For example, in this case, I want my object "test" behave like the string "ABCDEFG" when I compare it to another string. I think this should be done in the **iter** function but it doesn't seem to work.

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.var)

>>> test = Test("ABCDEFG")
>>> print "EF" in test # I want this to return True
False
>>> print "EF" in "ABCDEFG" # this is how test should behave
True
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to overload the [`__contains__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) special method to control the behavior of `in` with your class:

```
>>> class Test(object):
...     def __init__(self, var):
...         self.var = var
...
...     def __contains__(self, substr):
...         return substr in self.var
...
>>> test = Test("ABCDEFG")
>>> print "EF" in test
True
>>> print "YZ" in test
False
>>>
```

The [`__iter__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__) special method (which you should still overload for a custom string type) is for producing an iterator over a container class.  In other words, it makes your class iterable:

```
>>> class Test(object):
...     def __init__(self, var):
...         self.var = var
...
...     def __contains__(self, substr):
...         return substr in self.var
...
...     def __iter__(self):
...         return iter(self.var)
...
>>> test = Test("ABCDEFG")
>>> for i in test: print i   # This works because of Test.__iter__
...
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
>>>
```